# App Crashes on HTTPGET call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

I'm working on an android application, which send request to the server for `get some data`, but the problem is when I lost the **network connection** my app get **crashed**. or if I forget to change the **IP-Address** the application get crashed too. I have observed this problem just in the cast of **HTTPGET**, not in **HTTPPOST**. I have also checking the `Network Availability` but it's still remain crashed. I want show a Toast Message to the user when my application **lost the connection** instead of **crashing**. I'm sharing the snappet below. can someone please review it n sort out my issue. I don't know where I went wrong

**CODE:**

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            cellphoneDate = params[0];

                Log.e("Alert---Service","Calling Service now (: ");
                //Calling service now
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GETTING_ALERTS_URL + "/"
                        + cellphoneDate);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                try {
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                isInternetPresent = cm.isConnected();
                if(isInternetPresent)
                {
                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();      
                    try {
                        Serv_Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        if (Serv_Response != null) {
                            ////////////////////////////new code for getting list ///////////////////
                            JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(Serv_Response);
                            JSONArray alertName = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

                            for (int i = 0; i < alertName.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = alertName.getJSONObject(i);
                                String alert_title = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_TITLE);
                                Alerts alertObject = new Alerts();
                                alertObject.setAlertTitle(alert_title);
                                alertsList.add(alertObject);
                                }

                        }
                        }  catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            return null;
        }
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "From Database :" + Serv_GettingQuiz_Response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //String array[] = new String[size]; 
            if(Serv_Response.equals("{\"DoitResult\":[]}"))
            {
                //DoNothing
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < alertsList.size() ; i++ )
            {
                Log.e("Alert---Serice", "POP-UP notification");
            showNotification(alertsList.get(i).getAlertTitle(), "TAP for More Details", i);
            flag = true;
            //  savingDate(Serv_GettingQuiz_Response);
            }
        }
```

**LogCat:**

```
06-23 23:53:53.625: W/System.err(8610): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.9 refused
06-23 23:53:53.635: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
06-23 23:53:53.635: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-23 23:53:53.645: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-23 23:53:53.645: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:367)
06-23 23:53:53.655: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
06-23 23:53:53.655: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
06-23 23:53:53.655: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
06-23 23:53:53.665: W/System.err(8610):     at com.smartclasss.alerts.MyService$DoInBackground.doInBackground(MyService.java:169)
06-23 23:53:53.675: W/System.err(8610):     at com.smartclasss.alerts.MyService$DoInBackground.doInBackground(MyService.java:1)
06-23 23:53:53.675: W/System.err(8610):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-23 23:53:53.675: W/System.err(8610):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-23 23:53:53.685: W/System.err(8610):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-23 23:53:53.685: W/System.err(8610):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-23 23:53:53.695: W/System.err(8610):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-23 23:53:53.695: W/System.err(8610):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
06-23 23:53:53.695: W/System.err(8610): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.9 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
06-23 23:53:53.715: W/System.err(8610):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
06-23 23:53:53.715: W/System.err(8610):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-23 23:53:53.715: W/System.err(8610):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-23 23:53:53.725: W/System.err(8610):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:873)
06-23 23:53:53.725: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:125)
06-23 23:53:53.735: W/System.err(8610):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-23 23:53:53.735: W/System.err(8610):     ... 14 more
06-23 23:53:53.735: W/System.err(8610): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
06-23 23:53:53.755: W/System.err(8610):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
06-23 23:53:53.755: W/System.err(8610):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
06-23 23:53:53.755: W/System.err(8610):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-23 23:53:53.765: W/System.err(8610):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-23 23:53:53.765: W/System.err(8610):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Whenever there is a crash, it helps to post the stacktrace. Otherwise, there is no way for us to give you good advice.

Comment: @SkyKelsey thanks for your response,whenever my app get crashed, it catch the exception, but didn't execute the onPostExecute() func. why is it so ?

Comment: add your stack trace !!

Comment: Add the logcat/stacktrace. You should check internet connection before you start the asynctask. And certainly NOT, as you do now, AFTER httpClient.execute().

Comment: How can you loose network connection if you are on a local (w)lan? Running around in the garden with your phone?

Comment: yeah exactly @greenapps.. im also checking the internet connection before starting the Asyntask.

Comment: Better buy a new wifi router. Test your app in other networks to be sure.

Comment: @greenapps what if I lost the connection after entering in Asyntask?

Comment: If you have good try/catch blocks and check for null pointers after catch blocks your app can never crash. Do you null Serv_Response before doInBackground?

Comment: @greenapps i have uploaded the snappit, could you tell me how can I make it better?

Comment: So be sure Serv_Response == null at start. In onPostExecute check for null as it can be null there. It crashes now in onPostExecute.

Comment: @greenapps I'll try then then let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for an internet connection before you execute your request. Also, if there is an exception executing the request, don't just print out the stacktrace, you also need to stop processing the request.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this then let you know (: